# How to submit multiple users into the database

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

- First I have a button that creates a user info form.
- Second user fills out the form.
- Third I add that user to a list and new form.
- Last I want to submit that list of users to the database.

I am stuck on the last part. Since each participant has first_name, last_name and workshop_id. How do I submit something like that to the database? I normally use ajax to send it to a database processing page. But that's usually just one user. I really don't know how to go about setting up the data-string for submission.

```
<form id="participants">
    <div class="participant">
        <input type="text" name="workshop_id" class="workshop_id"  />
        <input type="text" name="first_name" class="first_name" />
        <input type="text" name="last_name" class="first_name" />
    </div>
    <div class="participant">
        <input type="text" name="workshop_id" class="workshop_id"  />
        <input type="text" name="first_name" class="first_name" />
        <input type="text" name="last_name" class="first_name" />
    </div>
    <div class="participant">
        <input type="text" name="workshop_id" class="workshop_id"  />
        <input type="text" name="first_name" class="first_name" />
        <input type="text" name="last_name" class="first_name" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What framework are you using on the server side? jQuery is a client JavaScript library only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to send an array of values via `$.ajax`

```
<form id="participants">
    <div class="participant">
        <input type="text" name="workshop_id[]" class="workshop_id"  />
        <input type="text" name="first_name[]" class="first_name" />
        <input type="text" name="last_name[]" class="first_name" />
    </div>
    <div class="participant">
        <input type="text" name="workshop_id[]" class="workshop_id"  />
        <input type="text" name="first_name[]" class="first_name" />
        <input type="text" name="last_name[]" class="first_name" />
    </div>
    <div class="participant">
        <input type="text" name="workshop_id[]" class="workshop_id"  />
        <input type="text" name="first_name[]" class="first_name" />
        <input type="text" name="last_name[]" class="first_name" />
    </div>
</form>
```

The post will be normal but the backend language will convert it to an Array. Eg: in php

`$_POST['workshop_id'][0];`

I found some more information [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays)

Comment: interesting... I've never done that before. What might the data-string look like?